# ZF2: Get current controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'd like to get the name of current controller in a view helper. I've tried using *$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');* mentioned in another post but is not working. Is it because i'm using it in the helper? Is there another way to get the current controller name?

Comment: have you tried in the getViewHelperConfig of your module when you declare your factories to actually have a function to set your controller name?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass HelperPluginManager to your view helper in constructor and then:
$vhiewHelperManger->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller'))

But this work only if you wont use forward plugin in controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()
```